# Get variable count and names from template.docx in PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

Is it possible to get number of variables and their names from docx template in PHPWord?

variable names in Template1.docx begin with **myvar_** : {myvar_1},{myvar_2},...,{myvar_**n**}

How do I get **n** as number of variables and their name (myvar_1, myvar_2, myvar_3,..)

Thank you,-

================== edited =============

Okay, I found the function getVariables() in "TemplateProcessor.php"

the code is:

```
$tulis = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('template1.docx');
$getvar = $tulis->getVariables();

echo 'Number of Variables: ' .count($getvar). '<br>';
for($i=0; $i<count($getvar); $i++) {
    echo 'varname [' .$i. ']: ' .$getvar[$i]. '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hi @mbahfelix, Please post the code that you have written

Comment: Hi @amansoni211, I have found the answer

Answer (score 0):

[this code also working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XdzR.png)

you check to include files

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).